# Minimalization of one variable function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima

I am trying to solve the problem of finding a point, which minimizes the time required to move from some point to another, some of the time swimming, some running, anyways in order to do that i have to minimize the function:

$$f(x)=\frac{(x^2+c^2)^{1/2}}{a}+\frac{((x-d)^2+(c-e)^2)^{1/2}}{b},$$

which unfortunately leads to very ugly things, when taking derivative. Is there another, maybe tricky way of finding minimum of this function?

Comment: Isn't this problem a variant of the shortest path problem which is solved by Descartes law of refraction?

Comment: If the problem is the one I believe, there is slight mistake in the question you asked : the $d$ in $(c-d)^2$ is not the same $d$ as in $(x-d)^2$

Comment: yeah, sorry, so many variables that i got lost :) its not the same d obviousely

Comment: It may be easier to find the minimum of $h(x)=b\sqrt{x^2+c^2}+a|x-d|$

Comment: @Vasya and why would the two be equivalent? I am not sure if you can get rid of the constant in the second square root

Comment: I assume that all constants are positive, in that case $(c-e)^2$ does not affect the location of minimum. We can also multiply $f(x)$ by $ab$ without changing where $max/min$ is going to be

Comment: I think this way of thinking is wrong, take f(x)>=0, then $min f(x) =min f(x)^{2}$ and see that $f(x)^2$ clearly depends on this constant

Comment: @ryszardeggink: The value of maximum will be different but not the location of maximum. take $\sqrt{x^2+9}$, $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, both have minimum at $x=0$. Compare with minimum of $|x|$.